# Add class to parent on focusin

Tags: javascript

I want to add the class name *active* to the parent `<label>` of `this`. Can't figure out why it's only targeting the first input. No jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/58ddtbm9/

```
document.querySelector('.contact input, .contact textarea').addEventListener("focusin",  function () {

    this.classList.add('active');;

});

document.querySelector('.contact input, .contact textarea').addEventListener("focusout",  function () {

    this.classList.remove('active');;

});
```

Comment: querySelector returns the first element, maybe you want querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` only returns the first match so you need `querySelectorAll` instead. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/58ddtbm9/1/) is an updated version of your fiddle.

And here is the modified JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.contact input, .contact textarea');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('focusin', function() {
        this.classList.add('active');
    });

    inputs[i].addEventListener('focusout', function() {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hai. Just noticed this does not work in FireFox. Any idea why?

Comment: Apparently Firefox does not support the focusin/focusout events (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin#Browser_compatibility)). You can use the corresponding focus/blur events instead.

Comment: Ta. Figured this out last night. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `querySelectorAll` and then loop over each result and add an event to each element. `querySelector` only returns the first match.